# Syntax error Android/Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, syntax-error, task

I'm trying to create a timer but I'm stuck. My code looks like this

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    };
}
timer.schedule(this,1000,1000);
```

But in the last line I have this error "Syntax error on token "timer", delete this token". I might add that I import

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

but I still have a problem.

Comment: rename `timer` => `tt`

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev Ohh before i edited it was tt instead of this

Answer (score 0):

Update your code

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
timer.schedule(tt, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: When i use this one i get "Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", delete this token
 - Syntax error on tokens, VariableDeclarator expected 
  instead"

Comment: Get me your complete method snippet

Comment: I used your code before i just trying to do something and i have changed "tt" on "this" so it's the same and ";" just made more mess

Comment: at all this is all method

Comment: confirm your variable names and  make sure you have put ';'  after timer task.

Comment: Timer t = new Timer();
     TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             //do something
         }
     };
     t.schedule(tt,1000,1000);  just copy-paste this code snippet instead pf your's

Comment: I used your code and still i have errors multiple markers and after clean up  still syntax

Comment: This code is running absolutely fine. If you still got errors they are elsewhere. You might post the whole class.